# angular.dart components with bootstrap.js fails due to shadow dom

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am playing around with **Angular.dart** as app framework and trying Twitters **Bootstrap** components and CSS for styling. I did run into an issue almost immediately, since **Bootstrap** does not seem to handle **ShadowDOM**, and **Angular.dart** uses the **ShadowDOM** for **Components**.

This would essentially mean I **cant build Angular components with Bootstrap.js**. Using Bootstrap components only requiring CSS works fine with `applyAuthorStyles: true` in `NgComponent` annotation.

Is there any way to also build angular.dart components using bootstrap js components?

/Cenk

Answer (score 5):

Several things can be fixed using `applyAuthorStyles: true` but selectors that cross the shadowDOM boundary don't work. You would have to change Bootstrap's css.

**applyAuthorStyles is deprecated or already removed**

Here [Feature Request: Add templates for NgDirectives or a NgComponent non-shadow dom option](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/367) is also a discussion going on about this topic.
It mentions a `ng-pseudo` directive that should help solving this issue.

AFAIK ShadowDOM will be ported to AngularJS as well maybe this creates some ally and eventually an improvment.

Polymer (JS and Dart) have the same problem.

Comment: applyAuthorStyles is deprecated and will be removed soon (if it wasn't already)